# PhoneGap Build Service "Build in HTML5, CSS, JavaScript" claim

Tags: javascript, css, html, cordova

The [PhoneGap build service](https://build.phonegap.com/) says you can build an app in HTML5, CSS, and JavaScript.  However, The phonegap.js is not available for each device (latest download PhoneGap 1.8.1 does not have one for Bada or iOS).  So I think the build service is meant to save us from creating the shells for each environment, but I fail to see how the PhoneGap API is supposed to work.

I thought the idea too was that you could build one code base for each environment.  I know there are quirks, but why is there a separate phonegap.js file for Android, WebOS, etc.?

The lack of documentation has me confused.

Comment: I developed a PhoneGap app by creating the project in visual studio, then i developed the html5/js/css3 in aptana studio 3, put it in the www folder of the pg project. ziped the project folder, uploaded it to the phoengap builder service, 2minutes later I could download a native app that could be installed for each mobile OS phonegap supports...

Comment: @furier awesome, so to use the phonegap API, where did you get the JS file?  Or is that imported for you when you upload to the build service?

Comment: the phonegap js file is only used to get access to phone specific functionality like gps, camera etc. if you don't need any of that there is no use for the js file really. But anyways, using the visual studio setup the js file for windowsphone is included already. you don't need the other js files to compile it with the build service to the other native OS apps. They have some kind of process that does that automagic for you... :)

Comment: no problem, glad to be of help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, there are separate files for each but when using phonegap build if you want to include a universal file for the build there is a way, put `<script src="phonegap.js"></script>` in your index.html file and don't include any js files, you actually don't even need the phonegap.js file, when I did this and ran it through phonegap build it attached the appropriate .js file to the appropriate build and I suddenly could use the phonegap API's for all the builds I was testing

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas on an approach similar to this without using the build service?

Answer (score 1):

The phonegap framework is made for specific Mobile Operating Systems.  The reason why there are so many is because each framework is for each type of operating system.  Like for games, most only work for Windows and some for mac, but very little support for Linux based systems.  Phonegap creates APIs for using the camera and other functionalities of the operating system.

Phonegap has their tutorials to show you how to install for iOS and Android.  I have not developed for newer systems.

Many people use [jQueryMobile](http://www.jquerymobile.com) to develop with PhoneGap to create a nice simple mobile application.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, supposedly the build service allows you not to have to create the wrappers for android, ios, etc.  You can just focus on the HTML only.  In addition, in the latest download there is no phonegap.js for ios, so I'm really confused by that...

Comment: The confusing part is why you believe that.  The release clear states that it fixes an issue for iOS.  Also, I downloaded the latest release and iOS is included.

http://phonegap.com/2012/06/13/phonegap-1-8-1-released/

Comment: so you see a phonegap.js in the ios folder???  I see the server-side code, but my download doesn't have phonegap.js for ios...

Comment: Yes, I do.  I'm not sure why you don't see it

Answer (score 0):

Whilst there are different phonegap.js files for each device, they are very similar (I found this out because I accidentally copied it from an iOS project to the Android one a few times). The differences are important but they do pretty-much work as-is.

The main reason they differ is that they just expose the underlying functionality provided by the Phonegap device-native code (Java, OC etc), which IS device-dependent. The Phonegap devs just take care of hiding that from you. All of the phonegap.js files expose the same functionality, they just connect sometimes to different places 'on the inside'. Hence the differences.

Most source 'you or I' would write for a Phonegap app is device-independent as a result of the above.